# Bash. Как ускорить работу сценариев?

Tags: linux, bash, unix, sh

Как можно ускорить выполнение сценария в linux?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Любая оптимизация - творческий процесс. И она очень зависит от того - что и до каких пор можно/нужно соптимизировать

1. исследовать сам скрипт на предмет нелепых неоптимальностей (многократный вызов одной и той же команды, что бы только проверить её вывод разными средствами и т.п.)
2. исключить вывод на терминал, заменить его выводом в файл, если данные нужны
3. сложную логику реализовать "внутренними" скриптами на awk - часто спасает.
4. в пункте 3 awk можно заменить на python/perl/что-то ещё
5. математику заменить на bc/octave/r
6. по максимуму отказаться от файловый операций (промежуточные временные файлы и т.п.)
7. кешировать результаты выполнения однотипных команд (сохранять вывод в переменной или в файлы)
8. использовать плюшки Bash/Zsh/другого вашего интерпретатора
9. что-то ещё...
10. переписать на tcl/perl/python/C/C++/Java/Go/Rust/.......

Answer (score 1):

Критичные по скорости решения лучше не делать на bash, но во всяком случае проверьте, какие команды в скрипте вы можете завершить `&` - таким образом переведя их в фоновый режим:

```
data > ./file &
```

только помните, что нельзя нитить таким образом, например, создание переменных.

Замените медленные части программы на bash, быстрыми программами на C.